# How do I override the models and controllers in a plugin in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How can I override a CakePHP plugin from application? I see that overriding of a view is very simple (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-views-from-inside-your-application), but how can I override a controller or a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot override any plugin class files in your app like you can do for view files. Just make a copy of the plugin and modify required class files.

Comment: This solution isn’t too flexible. If I have my core files in the plugins, it can be very convenient just simple override the necessary files in app. I hope there is a way to do this. For example I really like the solution of Kohana or Symfony 2 for it. I hope there is a solution for it in CakePHP too…

Comment: Overriding will ignore those methods (unless you are extending them by calling Parent::method in the override). So if you plan on overriding the methods, why not just change the code to do what you expect. It seems much easier to me thank trying to go through the complexities of overriding.

Comment: Because it can be very practical if I can share the plugin level things among the projects without any modification and I can override things (models, views, controllers etc.) only in the current project's app directory (if necessary). In this case I don't need to touch the plugins.

Answer (score 5):

You can override and extend plugin views modeld and controllers. There is a good example of doing this in the below link.

https://github.com/CakeDC/users#how-to-extend-the-plugin

Basically this is the summary... In your model you need to declare it like so.

`App::uses('UsersController', 'Users.Controller');`

`class AppUsersController extends UsersController {`

`}`